# POSTFIX auth can't get logged in

Tags: postfix, authentication, login, sasl

I try to setup my postfix smtp with sasl auth. It seems to be working when I check it with telnet on the local server.

ouput:

```
# telnet mail.domain.tld smtp
Trying 37.34.52.199...
Connected to mail.domain.tld.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.domain.tld ESMTP Postfix
ehlo domain.tld
250-mail.domain.tld
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

But When I try to test the auth to login, I am stuck with the username:

```
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dXNlcm5hbWUK
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

Username created as follow:

```
 # echo 'username' | base64
```

I am sure the user exists, I logged in to IMAP with the same user aswel.

postconf output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = domain.tld
myhostname = mail.domain.tld
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do your logs mention anything useful? and is dovecot set up correctly to provide the authentication listener at `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth`?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use swaks to test postfix.

```
swaks -s mail.domain.tld --to user@exmaple.net --from user@domain.tld --auth LOGIN --auth-user user@domain.tld
```

Comment: I restarted postfix and the Authentication works :X oei sorry for this one!